# Ajax works on Firefox but not on Internet Explorer - Need to update an XML file - No error message received

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

Well below you will find the code. I am trying to update an xml file with some answers that I will receive from the user
However IE is not updating the file....
Could you please assist me?

```
    function updateXML(newtext, newtext2)
     {
     var xmlhttp;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
   {// code for IE6, IE5


       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {

       return xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","here goes the url to retrieve xml data",true);

  xmlhttp.send();

}
```

I got most of this code from w3schools.com

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: For future reference, [w3schools.com is considered more harmful than helpful](http://w3fools.com/) these days.  There is [a list of better resources for learning](http://w3fools.com/#what-should-be-done) at that link as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [JQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It will take care of the browser inconsistencies for you.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

Comment: @DKinzer hmm however... is there a way to fix it without having to use a jquery? I don't handle it pretty much.... also, I have to call the updatexml function into other javascript function..... how could I do that if i'm going to use jquery???

Comment: @Natalia  there's an example on the page that shows you how to call another function on success.

Comment: WOW !! JQUERY is amazing :D  I finally was able to complete it!

Comment: @DKinzer Thank you ! well i will have to post my answer after 6 hours because I'm new...